# Prevent parallel uploads in Jquery Form plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload

I am using Jquery Form Plugin to upload files using onchange event listener on the file upload input element to upload the file as soon as it is selected.

I want to allow only one file at a time to be uploaded and adding the rest in a queue to be uploaded once the existing upload is complete.

I tried making this happen by using a variable and setting it false in beforeSubmit and then switching it back to true once the upload is complete. However, it keeps turning true automatically.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
var allowUpload = true;
console.log('initial');

var options = {    
        beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit,  
        uploadProgress: OnProgress,
        success:       afterSuccess,
        resetForm: true        
    }; 

 $('#upload').change(function() { 
    console.log(allowUpload);
    if(allowUpload)
    {
        console.log('onchange:' + allowUpload);
        $('#uploadForm').ajaxSubmit(options); 
    }
    return false; 
    });

function afterSuccess(data)
{
   allowUpload = true;
   console.log('aftersuccess' + allowUpload);
}
function beforeSubmit(data)
{
   allowUpload = false;
   console.log(allowUpload);
}
```

Comment: Check out the source code of this site: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/progress3.html

Comment: That demo is allowing concurrent uploads. I want to create a queue of uploads and then upload one after the another.

Comment: Okay, we can fix that.  Could you explain a little more in detail what the client must do, what it looks like to him/her?  I think the easiest solution is to generate multiple form elements, each with 1 file input. When the client selects a file, a new form appears.  Once one form is done, we trigger the second ... And an array checks for doubles.  In the mean time the client can select files any time, they are put at the end of the queue.  Interested?

Comment: Emmanuel, I had thought about it. I am just trying to avoid it. I was wondering if there was any other way to achieve this. 
Basically, the client will see an upload button, when they click on it, they can choose the file and it starts getting uploaded, then while the upload is happening, they can choose another file using the same button but the new file should start getting uploaded once the earlier is done uploading.

Comment: Oh, but you can do all this with just 1 button, that's not the problem.  I'm talking HTML, the client wouldn't notice anything (providing some css).  The problem is the input type="file".  As long as the file is being uploaded, the client (probably) shouldn't use that same element. Also, how do you provide a queue if there is only 1 element?

Comment: I figured there might be a way using setTimeout between each time upload to delay the upload process but I haven't actually been able to make something on that concept. I am still working on it though.